Problem to send my formData instance via axios with content-type multipart/form -data
I'm working on vue3 and I want to send my form data which may contain a file image to my API via axios request but I still have a problem. If I inspect the formData instance, all values ​​are present but are ignored when my axios Content-Type header are set to multipart/form-data. I also use Pinia in my work to store my functions. Can someone help me please?
My Pinia function
async createEnterprise(data) {
        
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("logo", data.value.logo, data.value.logo.name);
    formData.append("name", data.value.name);
    formData.append("email", data.value.email);
    formData.append("phone", data.value.phone);
    formData.append("address", data.value.address);
            
    try {
       const response = await axios.post('/api/auth/entreprises/store', formData, {
             headers: {
                 "Authorization": `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                 "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
                 "Accept": "application/json"
                    },
                  data: formData
           }) 

       const data = await response.data;
                
    } catch (error) {
        this.errors = error.response.data.errors;            
    }
},

My create view in vue
const data = ref({
        name: "",
        email: "",
        phone: "",
        address: "",
        logo: null
    });

    const handleFileChange = (event) => {
        let logo = event.target.files[0];
        data.value.logo = logo;
    }

    const submitForm = async () => {
        try {
            await createEnterprise(data);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log("Error submitting form: " + error);
        }
    }

<form @submit.prevent="submitForm">
     <div class="create__form__group">
          <label for="logo" class="create__label">Logo:</label>
          <p class="text-sm opacity-75 indent-3">Cliquer dans le vide pour charger le logo</p>
          <label class="create__file__label border border-gray-200 hover:border-4 hover:border-blue-200">
               <div class="file__upload__icon">
                   <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 24 24"      fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" 
stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-image">
            <rect x="3" y="3" width="18" height="18" rx="2" ry="2"></rect>
                                                <circle cx="8.5" cy="8.5" r="1.5"></circle>
                                                <polyline points="21 15 16 10 5 21"></polyline>
                                            </svg>
                                        </div>
             <input type="file" accept="image/*" class="focus:outline-none focus:ring focus:ring-blue-200"
                                        @change="handleFileChange">
             <p class="file__info">Aucun fichier sélectionné</p>
          </label>
          <p class="error" v-if="enterprisesStore.errors.logo">{{ enterprisesStore.errors.logo[0] }}</p>
                                    
     </div>   
</form>

When I submit the form, the result of the data still empty with all fields input filled, That means the input fields values are not sent

How can you confirm the values aren't being sent and not a server issue? You can check via devtools > network tab > select the request executed > payload tab.

It's not a server issue because all requests passed, if I send the form with the value of Content-Type set to "application/json" without uploading the file, the values of input fields are correctly sent

Just leave out the Content-Type header, axios will be able to figure it out on its own. https://axios-http.com/docs/multipart

ok, I will try it
